# Probability generating function of $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $N$ is a a positive integer r.v.

Tags: generating-functions

Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where all $X_i$'s are iid and $N$ and $X_i$ are independent where $N$ is a positive-valued integer r.v.

Then the PGF of $X$ is
$$G_{X}(s) = \mathbb{E}(s^X)
$$
They simplified this down to:
$$G_{X}(s) = \mathbb{E}(\prod_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}(s^{X_i})) \\ 
= \mathbb{E}(G_{X_i}(s)^N)\\
= G_{N}(G_{X_i}(s)) \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (G_{X_i}(s))^n \mathbb{P}(N=n)
$$
My question is: why do they use the probability density function of $N$ to compute the expectation in the end? So how did they go from the third last equality to the second last?
Because it seems unclear whether to use $X_i$ or $N$, since $X_i$ is also a random variable here. Can't I do this:
$$
G_{X}(s) = \mathbb{E}(G_{X_i}(s)^N) = \mathbb{E}((\exp(N)))^{\log(G_{X_i}(s))}) 
$$
and then use the PDF of $X_i$?
I think my question boils down to: **how do I know what PDF to use?**

Comment: What dose the PDF mean?

Comment: Probability Density Function

Comment: Are you familiar with measure theory. Not all random variables have densities so the only way to find the generating function is to write as an integral. The integral then has to be split into the disjoint subsets $\{N=n\}$.